# Does virtualenv just modify the pythonpath?

Tags: virtualenv

I'm deploying Django on a production server together with virtualenv, and am having trouble activating virtualenv on the server with

```
source .../bin/activate
```

I did a little research, and found that the pythonpath is changed depending on if we are or aren't in a virtualenv.

sys.path (with virtualenv activated)

```
['',
'/.../virtualenv/test_path/bin',
'/.../virtualenv/test_path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
'/.../virtualenv/test_path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
'/.../virtualenv/test_path/lib/python2.7',
'/.../virtualenv/test_path/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/.../virtualenv/test_path/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/.../virtualenv/test_path/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/.../virtualenv/test_path/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/.../virtualenv/test_path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
'/.../virtualenv/test_path/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

sys.path (without activating virtualenv):

```
['',
'/usr/local/bin',
'/usr/lib/python2.7',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gst-0.10',
'/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
'/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7',
'/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/IPython/extensions']
```

Is is sufficient to just change the pythonpath to point to the virtualenv

```
.../python2.7/site-packages
```

folder to get the same results as running

```
source .../bin/activate
```

?

Comment: Just a little note. $PYTHONPATH is an environmental variable, which is included in sys.path list. This is actually done when Python starts up in a module called site.py. Virtualenv does not modify $PYTHONPATH, but installs a modified version of site.py in the virtual environment folder created by virtualenv.

Comment: @J.P.Petersen Thank you! That was information I was looking for!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not. virtualenv is not only about `site-packages`, it is about a whole isolated python environment.

Doing `source /path/to/venv/bin/activate` just changes your `$PATH` environment variable to include your virtualenv `bin` directory as first lookup.

If you call `python` directly, it is just a shortcut for:

```
$ /path/to/venv/bin/python myscript.py
```

And if you call `pip` in an activated virtualenv, it is the same as:

```
$ /path/to/venv/bin/pip install XYZ
```